# Fitting for cable entry to home?

Tags: electrical

I need to make solar PV cable enter my home, horizontally through a hole in a wall. There are four insulated wires in two separate 1" conduits but there is one hole through which they must go in.

Is there some electrical fitting I can use for this entry, to cover the hole and make it look proper? I was thinking of attaching a junction box. No building codes apply where I live.

**Edit:** Here is a picture as requested. Currently there is only one conduit but there will be two. Also the conduits can be made to come up form the bottom.

[image]

Comment: How about a picture?

Comment: "No building codes apply where I live" when people say that they usually think that because they rarely see enforcement actions, but they're there.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica For the purpose of an answer you can assume that there aren't any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of simple solutions. One would be a simple PVC raintight junction box. You would drill holes for the 2 conduits coming in and one in the back for entering the home. Use the right sized male adapters.  Be sure to caulk where it enters the home, esp. if subject to weather. If subject to severe weather you might look into using rain tight fittings (yeah, I know, nothings "really" rain tight, but we do our best).  You could also use an entrance ell (tee type) that has can accomodate 3 conduits.

[image: PVC Jbox]

Answer (score 1):

You could try an electrical bulkhead fitting :

[image]

A wire grommet:

[image]

or an ell:

[image]

Comment: All three would work only with a single conduit. I could use a Tee though.